# Not receiving any push notification in iOS (PhoneGap) Application

Tags: ios, iphone, laravel, phonegap

I have created an app in PhoneGap. I am sending push notifications from a PHP API created in Laravel **(Edujugon/PushNotification)**.

Android notifications are working OK but push notifications for iPhone are not working.

I have used the correct certificate as using this certificate I can send the notification from http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/

Even in the PHP code I am getting success message as :

```
(
    [success] => 3
    [failure] => 0
    [tokenFailList] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Any help on this.

Comment: Please share the code snippet too, for adding push notification in phonegap app.

Comment: I am sending push notification from PHP (Laravel API)

Comment: which push notification library did you use? apple's native `apns` or `firebase`?

Comment: Edujugon/PushNotification - https://github.com/edujugon/PushNotification

Comment: I have used apple's native APNS

Comment: Any suggestion ?